# Project in ambiguous state in TFS

Tags: tfs

I have a project that's in an ambiguous state in TFS.
The project is mapped under my solution and it is inside the directory TFS is mapped to, however, the cjproj itself is not in there. I was able to include files underneath the project node by excluding and recincluding them in the solution, but no such option is available for the csproj file itself.

Note the projects were to the solution via 'Add existing project'.
Additionally they were projects that were formerly on the TFS server but had at some point been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can go to the source control explorer and add files, including csproj from there.

Comment: When you add existing files/projects, you always need to include them manually through source control explorer. Unfortunately, TFS still works on file basis and has many troubles with the "Add existing ..."  function.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, consult the "Solution Binding" dialog.  (File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control)

Here's [an article I wrote awhile ago](http://blogs.msdn.com/richardb/archive/2007/06/04/intro-to-solution-binding-in-tfs-plus-bonus-faq.aspx) on how solution binding works in TFS.  It's very different from what you may be used to with other Visual Studio source control providers.